# How can I make my wiki page mutable again?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I found the packaging process very confusing I wanted to add a new document explaining it bottom up. Now suddenly the page became immutable and I have no idea why. This is the link (early draft): http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/ReleasingAPackage

Thanks in advance for any help on that problem![image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252107/how-can-i-make-my-wiki-page-mutable-again?/) by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:
Afaict, the page is editable. I just saved a trivial change. Do you get an error saying otherwise?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:
Btw: section "4.3 - Update your package.xml" is definitely not optional. If you don't tag the repository and get your manifests to match the tags, things will not work.

**Comment by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on 2017-01-16**:
Udpate: I appended a screenshot showing you what I a talking about - I can no longer edit the site and on the right panel "Immutable page" has appeared. Maybe it's just been blocked to me but I'd like to know if this persists..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:
The fact that your screenshot shows a "Login" link tells me you're currently not logged in. Could you login and try again?

**Comment by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on 2017-01-16**:
Wow thanks, that's true. Interesting as I am logged in here so I assumed I would be there too. I am no longer used to systems killing my Cookies while I am editing stuff, this shouldn't happen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are simply not logged in...

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on 2017-01-16**:
Good point, see the comment above. However I am not really content the way this is displayed - if I see immutable page I assume it actually *is* immutable. But okay, my fault in this case so whatever.